# Adding picture frame to a photo

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, save, xcode4.2

I am making an app that adds a picture frame to a photo.I would like to know how to have my Save button save both Images (the photo, and the frame) as one Image.Right now it only saves one of the images.

In interface builder I have the save action saving the image that is loaded into an ImageView, with the frame ImageView overlaying that image.

I'd like to merge the two photos as one, so the save action can save the image with the frame.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In this may need to use the masking in the iphone where the unnecessary thing of the image is automatically remove and attach with the frame.

I think this help to implement best for the your applications

So you can refer the following link for Download and tutorial and Source also.

[Reference link](http://sugartin.info/2011/10/21/mask-and-crop-of-an-image/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your link.but the link doesnt work :(.Can u provide any other link

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some drawing using Core Graphics. This code should do what you want, possibly with some  tweaks to the rectangles/sizes:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
[image drawRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
[frameImage drawRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```